# Drupal form #states using OR

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a part of my form display depending on the state of a select box. The select box code is:

```
$form['product_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Product Type'),
    '#options' => array(
      'a' => t('a'),
      'b' => t('b'),
      'c' => t('c'),
    ),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

I then have a field when I only wan to show it when the value is b or c.

```
$form['problem'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Problem'),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        array(
           ':input[name="product_type"]'=> array('value' => 'b'),
           ':input[name="product_type"]'=> array('value' => 'c'),
        ),       
      ),
    ),    
  );
```

What is happening is that what ever the last value in the page is being used.
I have found the following pages https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7 & https://drupal.org/node/1464758 but am still lost.

Comment: I've got the same issue. But for me works this solution https://www.drupal.org/node/735528#comment-9813979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is no right at all, this is the right way to make an OR:

```
$form['problem'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#title' => t('Problem'),
  '#states' => array(
    'visible' => array(
      array(
        ':input[name="product_type"]'=> array(
          array('value' => 'b'),
          array('value' => 'c'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Regards

Comment: I can't get this to work, it just seems to display regardless of which options are checked. I can get it to work when checking a single option.

Comment: If you can't get this to work and you are using the jquery update module then apply [the patch found over here](https://drupal.org/node/1448490).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your condition like this (instead of 2 different entries):

```
$form['problem'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#title' => t('Problem'),
    '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
            ':input[name="product_type"]'=> array(
                'value' => 'b',
                'value' => 'c',
            ),     
        ),
    ),    
);
```

Comment: This won't work because you have 2 keys that are both "value" so the second one will overwrite the first.

Comment: @FelixEve is correct: PHP will see just a single *value* key.